# Syntax Error Code: 1064 in MYSQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I couldn't get why it throws exception and took me a lot of my time. I would really appreciate any help.

this is mysql statement

```
 use dvdrental;

Select S.city From S OS
Where EXISTS (select top(1) S.city, 
 Count(S.s_num) From S In S
 Where In S.city = OS.city Group By S.city 
 Order by Count(S.s_num) DESC)
```

the exception is

```
  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in 
 your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
 corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '.city, 
Count(S.s_num) From S In S Where In S.city = OS.city Group By S.city Orde' at line 2
```

Thank You

Comment: MySql Workbench 6.3.10 @Nick

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The query doesn't make sense.  Sample data and desired results are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Be Specific because:

MYSQL: Doesn't have `TOP` like

```
select top(1)
```

You have to use like this:

```
limit 1
```

at the end

like this:

```
Select S.city From S OS Where EXISTS 
(select S.city, Count(S.s_num) From S In S Where In S.city = OS.city Group By S.city Order by Count(S.s_num) DESC  limit 1)
```

Comment: try to remove OS and replace `OS.City` to `S.City` be careful to your `aliases`

Comment: Did you try to remove the `top(1)`  and replace it to `limit 1` at the end?

Comment: use dvdrental;

Select S.city From S OS
Where EXISTS (select limit 1 S.city, Count(S.s_num) From S In S
Where In S.city = OS.city Group By S.city Order by Count(S.s_num) DESC)

Comment: put the limit 1 at the end

Comment: My question is: what you are going to exactly? maybe you can show your sample data and your expected output.